# Downloading PDF via PHP won't open in mobile

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, mobile

Generating a PDF from wkhtmltopdf working great on desktop. 
I have a two-step process to generate the file and then download the file.
The file generated opens just fine on my mobile device (when I e-mail it) but using a PHP script, I am unable to open after download.

In other words, it's not the PDF, it's the PHP download that's causing problems. The file downloads with the appropriate name, but won't open in mobile.

Galaxy S5 w/ Chrome (up-to-date).

The download is started with javascript:

```js
window.location = 'savePDF.php?file=' + filename + '&fileName=' + nameString;
```

And here's the PHP script:

```php
<?php
$file = $_GET['file'];

header('Pragma: public',true);
header('Expires: 0');
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$_GET['fileName'].'.pdf"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
unlink($file);
?>
```

EDIT: `unlink($file)` added to code to show that aspect.

Comment: Hope you are aware of the _huge_ security hole you are opening on your server, by accepting (by the looks of it) just any file name …?

Comment: Yes I'm aware. This is dumbed down for testing purposes. Thanks

Comment: Alrighty then; back to the topic, such issues are often caused by the headers, especially the ones regarding caching. Try removing `Expires` and `Cache-Control`, and see if that changes things.

Comment: Tried removing `Expires` and `Cache-Control`. Still no luck.

Comment: I assume downloading the file directly, not via the script, works on mobile? If so, try two things, 1) compare the file sizes of the file downloaded directly via the webserver, and via your script – are those identical? And if they are, 2) compare the HTTP response headers between the two – any significant differences there?

Comment: OK, so the two file sizes don't match... but why wouldn't they? If I link directly to the file, the download works.

Comment: Try opening them both in a hex editor and compare – maybe it’s just a few bytes at the beginning (the BOM comes to mind as a regular offender in such situations), or maybe there was some error message from your PHP script, that as part of the output got into the downloaded file …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Thanks to everyone for helping me debug (on mobile without dev tools it is a pain).

I was `unlink($file);` right after `readfile($file)` and for some reason on mobile (when it was asking what I wanted to do with the file before downloading) it was deleting the temporary file before reading the entire contents. Instead, I added:

```
exec("php cleantmp.php $tmpfile > NUL &");
```

and created cleantmp.php:

```
<?php
if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli') {
    sleep(10);

    unlink($argv[1]);
}
?>
```

Which now runs in the background and deletes the temp files after 10 seconds.

Thanks again for your help CBroe